# Factoring of a polynomial

Tags: algebra-precalculus, factoring

How can I factor the following polynomial

$$P(x)=x^3+ax^2+bx^2+cx^2+abx+acx+bcx+abc$$.

I have tried several ways but I couldn't find a solution for this.

Comment: Hint: $\;P(-a)=0\,$. Or just write it as $P(x)=x^3+(a+b+c)x^2+(ab+ac+bc)x+abc$.

Answer (score 0):

Expand $(x+a)(x+b)(x+c)$ and compare with the expression that you provided.

Comment: I have actually tried this one according to Vista's theorem but isn't there any other way?

Comment: Comparing with the Vieta's formula should give us a direction of how to guess the solution I believe. i.e. If you expand $(x-\alpha)(x-\beta)(x-\gamma)$, you will get a highly similar cubic equation but they differ in sign, we just have to figure out how to adjust the sign.